# VBA - Filter/Cut/Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how to write the VBA statement to

1. Filter Criteria1 (Gross Sales) in column `I`
2. Copy Criteria1
3. Paste data to column `K`
4. Filter Criteria2 in (Net Sales) column `I`
5. Copy Criteria2
6. Paste data to column `L`

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Range("A1:J1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="Gross Sale"
Columns("2" & ":" & Range("J70000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
```

Thanks in advance folks.

[image: Screenshot of Data]

Comment: The bit of code you have posted possibly works.  Without seeing the rest of the Sub, it's hard to tell what you problem is from what you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (modify "Sheet6" to your sheet's name) :

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFiltResults()

Dim FiltRng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet6") ' modify "Sheet6" to your sheet's name
    With .Range("A1:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
        ' set range filter column I to "Gross Sale"
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="Gross Sale"

        Set FiltRng = .Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        FiltRng.Copy .Range("K1") '<-- only copy visible cells to Column K
        Set FiltRng = Nothing '<-- clear range variable

        ' set range filter column I to "Net Sales"
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="Net Sales"
        Set FiltRng = .Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        FiltRng.Copy .Range("L1") '<-- only copy visible cells to Column L
    End With
End With

End Sub
```